# How can I get these queries to work together?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

The query is asking to find the course sets that their combination covers all the missing knowledge/skills for a person to pursue a pos_code. The considered course sets will not include more than three courses. If
multiple course sets are found, list the course sets (with their course IDs) in the order of the ascending order of the
course sets’ total costs.

The following SQL statement only finds the courses to pursue a pos_code.

```
SELECT c.c_code, c.title, c.c_level, c.description, t.ks_code, SUM(c.retail_price)
FROM course c 
INNER JOIN teaches t
ON c.c_code = t.c_code
INNER JOIN requires r 
ON r.ks_code = t.ks_code
WHERE r.pos_code = 1
GROUP BY c.c_code, c.title, c.c_level, c.description, t.ks_code, c.retail_price
ORDER BY c.retail_price ASC;
```

I now need to find the courses the person needs to pursue that position. 
For example, per_id = 5 has skills 1, 10, 15, 20, 25, 7.
The position we're trying to go for is pos_code = 1 which requires skills 1, 3, 5. The only courses that should be listed is courses that teach only skills 3 and 5 since the person knows skill 1.

Below is the other part of the query I'm trying to work on:

```
WITH missing_ks(ks) AS (
    (SELECT ks_code 
    FROM requires natural join position
    WHERE pos_code = 1)
    MINUS
    (SELECT ks_code
    FROM has_skill
    WHERE per_id = 5))
```

In the above query, it only tells me which skills this person is missing for that position. How would I go about combining these two queries together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am following correctly, I think all that you need is a not exists subquery.

Try this out and let me know what you think:

```
SELECT c.c_code, c.title, c.c_level, c.description, t.ks_code, SUM(c.retail_price)
FROM course c 
INNER JOIN teaches t
ON c.c_code = t.c_code
INNER JOIN requires r 
ON r.ks_code = t.ks_code
WHERE r.pos_code = 1
  AND not exists (select 1 from has_skill s
                   where per_id = 5
                     and t.ks_code = s.ks_code)
GROUP BY c.c_code, c.title, c.c_level, c.description, t.ks_code, c.retail_price
ORDER BY c.retail_price ASC;
```